# How do I prepare for a job outside of my country?

Tags: career-development, united-states, relocation, international

So I live in Puerto Rico and while I like it here, I decided to start looking for work opportunities in the US. I’m a 26 year old who just earned his BS from computer science and while I have been working at a small company for almost two years, I have no idea what to expect from the US.

So my question are the following:

1. What should one do to prepare for these type of changes?
2. Should I expect companies to ignore me because I’m not in the US mainland?
3. How does the whole relocation work?
4. Is it better to apply and then find places to live or vice versa?
5. Where can I find the information about the different paperwork that would be require for me to live? (I know DMV for driver’s license but if I need more information regarding for example moving my current vehicle or something like that)

Comment: Maybe a better fit for expatriates.stackexchange as it's about moving to another country?

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager Assuming Moving from Puerto Rico to the US mainland is not the same as expatriating.  There are no visa or work permit requirements.  There are no mobility restrictions.

Comment: @Eric - Probably closer than you think.  Relocation, moving then job hunting and differences are all things an expat deals with.  The fact it's the same legal/nationality is only part of it.  I was looking at one point at a move from the UK to the Caymans (a uk colony), it was more akin to being an expat than being in the UK, this is just a move in the opposite direction.

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager I've been an expat myself.  At Zaberiel's stage, your concerns as a potential expat are: am I legally allowed to move there and work?  Will my partner and family be allowed to come with me?  Will companies there hire me?  Once you get there you are faced with potentially learning a new language, dealing with an unfamiliar bureaucracy, being potentially unable to do basics (e.g. open a bank account) due to not yet having the required documentation.  The move from Puerto Rico to the US mainland will be worse than moving to a new state in the US, but not like expatriating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't get involved in large commitments (eg joining the board of a charity or signing up to tutor kids for a year).  Save money for the move as you may not get a relocation allowance or it may come as a re-embursement.  Decide on what you are going to move, sell/give away, or put into storage.  Figure out what international moving companies operate in your area and price out how much it would be to move to your top couple of choices of cities.

2/4. This is a bit of a catch.  If you have very marketable skills you may be able to catch a job from abroad but it will be much harder.  On the flip side while it is much easier to find a job from your destination you will be unemployed looking for work in a more expensive place with less support.  I would suggest trying for at least a couple of months from where you are and see how it goes.

3. Completely depends on what you negotiate with the company.  Some companies will have relocation policies so they have a starting point that you might get some concessions from.  Others do not and you will have to set your own starting point for negotiation.  At this point you should know how much the move and plane ticket will cost you so you can effectively negotiate.  Be aware that some companies will not even consider the idea of a relocation allowance so be mentally prepared if that is a dealbreaker for you.
4. Beaurocracy and paperwork may vary state to state so it's difficult to say exactly.  Things to consider when preparing to relocate would be moving a vehicle, pets, taxes, investments, and property.